# How to create sticky footer in unusual site structure?

Tags: html, css, footer

I have the following site structure:

```
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="wrp">....</div> 
      <footer class="footer">...</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The question is: how to create a sticky footer with such a structure? I tried different variants from different sources, but nothing fixed footer. It is just "flying" on the page. If you need CSS - type in comments.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```css
.wrp {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  font-size: .9em;
  padding: 25px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.footer a,
.footer {
  color: #838383;
}

.footer .midside {
  display: flex;
}

.footer .copyright {
  width: 100%;
}

.copyright a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

*P.S. This is my first question, so if I did something wrong-please,tell...*

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Yes, we need to see the code you have tried so that we have a [mcve]. Also there is nothing unusual about your site structure, except you don't close a div with `<div/>`... what's unusual about your structure and why is that relevant to the sticky footer not working?

Comment: Added some CSS. Dismiss that <div/>. Just typo.

Comment: So what problems have you run into making this sticky? None of the code seems relevant to a sticky footer or indicates an unusual site structure.

Comment: This is a clean CSS variant, without any sticky footer code. I mean, that I tried different footer snippets and nothing really helped me. I just wanna somebody to help me get a best skippet to make footer sticky. Hope, you understand me c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flex `column` with `min-height: 100vh` and with `.wrp` set to `flex-grow: 1` will put the footer at the bottom

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrp {
  max-width: 1350px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  font-size: .9em;
  padding: 25px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="wrp">wrp</div>
  <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use flexbox:

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;  
}

.wrp {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: .9em;
  padding: 25px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.footer a,
.footer {
  color: #838383;
}

.footer .midside {
  display: flex;
}

.footer .copyright {
  width: 100%;
}

.copyright a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: This snippet crashed my template :C

Comment: Keep the rest of your .wrp styles, just add flex: 1;

Comment: Also put a width on .wrp. I'll add a codepen to answer

Comment: @StefanBob you should make a working snippet with OP's code when you can, and not necessarily leave it up to them to fill in the gaps. And include your code on SO - no need to link to codepen when it isn't necessary. Links to codepen may break over time and won't be helpful to users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative positioning and place the footer at the bottom of the page.

```
.wrp {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height:calc(100vh - 100px); 
}
.footer {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:#111;
position:relative;
bottom:0px;

}
```

Here's the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mxd3aj8g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to footer class

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 60px;
  }
```

Set it at bottom of CSS . You might have to adjust bottom .